# Python 3: ftplib - nlst command does not show files starting with a point

Tags: python, ftplib, hidden-files

I've use ftplib (Python 3.4.2 on Mac OS X Yosemite) to connect to my local ftp server. the ftplib works fine, but i have the problem that the nlst command does not show a files that starts with a point (in my scenario a .htaccess file). When i use my terminal (Mac OS X) i can see the .htaccess file.

**Is there an special parameter for ftplib.nlst to show file with points a the beginning (hidden files)???**

I've also tried ftp.retrlines('NLST') and ftp.retrlines('LIST')

My code snippet:

```
with ftplib.FTP(__ftp_host,
                    __ftp_user,
                    __ftp_pwd) as ftp:
     print(str(ftp.nlst()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ftp.retrlines("LIST -a")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect. This is a client side solution. I've also found a server-side solution. I use proftpd. When i change the ListOptions from "-l" to "-a" it will force the server to always display hidden files.

Comment: but what about name of hidden files ? if I want delete hidden files, how i can get it full name ? the ftp.retrlines("LIST -a") command only show it and it look like linux command `ls -la`, this result is can't use in `for` cycle

Comment: i did it and wrote decision:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376558/get-hidden-files-in-ftp-server/48171298#48171298