# Get hidden files in FTP server

Tags: java, eclipse, ftp

I have the local server mockftpserver, and in the server there are couple of files and they are protected with a prefix '._' and the method to protect from getting those files is the following  :

```
protected String getRealPath(Session session, String path) {
    String currentDirectory = (String) session.getAttribute(SessionKeys.CURRENT_DIRECTORY);
    String result;
    if (path == null) {
        result = currentDirectory;
    }
    else if (getFileSystem().isAbsolute(path)) {
        result = path;
    }
    else {
        result = getFileSystem().path(currentDirectory, path);
    }
    return result.replace("._", "");
}
```

I tried to list the files in the FTP server I got them but the protected ones like '._passwrd' I was not able to see it. 
I used the normal method to get the file list:

```
boolean login = ftpClient.login("user", "password"); 

if (login) {  
    System.out.println("Connection established...");  
    FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();  

    for (FTPFile file : files) {  
        if (file.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE) {  
            System.out.println("File Name: "  
            + file.getName()  
            + " File Size: " );  
        }  
    }  
    String[] fil = ftpClient.listNames();
    if (files != null && fil.length > 0) {
        for (String aFile: fil) {
            System.out.println(aFile);
        }
    }
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String firstLine = null;

    try {
        InputStream stream = 
            ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("._"+"._passwd");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
        firstLine = reader.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) 
            try { 
                reader.close(); 
            } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
}
```

But thinking that the method will only check the name once, so if I added the ._ once again it should work. Although it did not or I could not apply it in the right way.

Comment: did you find answer ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about Java but in Python i solved similar task in the following way:
i used: FTP server, Python 2.7.12, library 'ftplib'
so i show just needed part with comments:

```
#while customer list not empty
while self.customerDirs:
    #create connect to root
    self.connection.cwd("/")
    #choose customer
    customer = self.customerDirs.pop()
    try:
        #go inside to customer's folder
        self.connection.cwd(customer)
        #for all folders inside
        for dir in self.connection.nlst():
        #go inside
        self.connection.cwd(dir)
        #create empty list
        hiddenList = []
        #create variable which contains path
        pathDir = self.connection.pwd()
        #write to list hidden files
        self.connection.retrlines("LIST -a", hiddenList.append)
        for entry in hiddenList:
            #split value and take file name
            entrySplit = entry.split(' ')[-1]
            #cheсk file name
            if entrySplit not in ['.', '..'] and entrySplit.startswith('.'):
                #all necessary files are sent to method which will delete it (lool like: /customer/folder/.hidden_file.hid)
                self.ftp_delete_file('/'.join([pathDir, entrySplit]))
                #return to step up
            self.connection.cwd("..")
```

that all, i hope it will be helpful information

Comment: I don't have time to review the quality of this answer right now - hopefully it is useful, but as far as I can see it's low quality. To mods: I'll try to make it better ASAP, if someone flags it, please don't remove it for 12h. Let's say that I take it under my wings ;)

Comment: OK, I've reviewed it and fixed indendation, but I cannot really figure out the point of the question, not even to mention the point of the answer. Feci quod potui, faciant meliora potentes.

Comment: as I understood it was necessary to get hidden files from FTP server, for examlpe in Python lib, `FTP.nlst()` method returns only visible file (without hidden files) and problem was in it, i.e. get name (or full path) files which started from '.'

Answer (score 0):

You should set your ftpClient to list hidden Files before listing the files, so:

```
ftpClient.setListHiddenFiles(true);
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
```